# For loop in simple R function is spitting out null vector

Tags: r, function, for-loop

I don't know why this is occurring, but I wrote a simple function and when I use a `for` loop within my function it keeps on spitting out a `null` vector.

```
power_vector_sample_size_sim = function(alpha){
  
  power_value_vector = vector(mode = "numeric")
  
    for(i in 1:10){  
    power_value_vector[i] = power_calc_simulation_by_samp(sample_size_1 = i, alpha_1 = alpha)
   } 
}
```

Here's the thing. The individual parts of the `for` loop work just fine and give me the desired result: a vector of length 10. That is if I just highlight the initialized variable and the `for` loop, the desired result comes about. But as soon as I try to wrap this up in a function then it goes `null`. I should add that above I have the argument `alpha` in the code, but when I was testing it I was using a numerical constant getting my desired results. I feel my scoping of the function is right, but something very small is stopping it from working. Thoughts?

Comment: `for` loops do not return anything. If you want your function to return `power_value_vector`, then your function should be `function(alpha) { power_value_vector <- vector(..); for (i in 1:10) { .. }; power_value_vector; }`.

Comment: shouldn't I be able to call `power_value_vector` once it has been populated by the `for` loop? The vector is not even populating when I look at it in the Global Environment.  EDIT: Your suggestion worked. I had other `for` loops I wrote previously, I didn't wrap them in a function though, so why would those be ok?

Comment: The premise of your `for` loop seems reasonable. I know nothing about your `power_calc_..` function, so the real answer is "I cannot know for certain". BTW, no `for` loop required, try `power_vector_sample_size_sim <- function(alpha) sapply(1:10, function(i) power_calc_simulation_by_samp(sample_size_1 = i, alpha_1 = alpha))`

Comment: I do need to get more comfortable using the various `applies`, that's why I resorted to the `for` loop. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: *"shouldn't I be able to call `power_value_vector`"* ... *inside* the function, yes, *outside* the function, no, it's been discarded. If I'm right, then realize that variables created inside the function are not accessible outside the function. As I said, add `power_value_vector` after your `for` loop as the last expression in the function. Now, you should be calling this as `ret <- power_vector_sample_size_sim(...)`, and then `ret` will have the results of what you called `power_value_vector` internally.